# Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web, interceptor

I follow Spring mvc course on Pluralsight, and I have "Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy" this error when running my application.
Before this, I added theese beans to servlet-config.xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="language" />
</mvc:interceptors>         

<bean id="localResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en" />
```

In resource folder I have two files. messages_es.properties and messages.properties. One has`goal.text=Minutos Ejercicio para el día de hoy:` and other `goal.text=Minutes Exercise For The Day Today:`
So the target is to choose the language.

And in jsp file I have this line about it

`Language : <a href="?language=en">English</a> | <a href="?language=es">Spanish </a>`

So how can I make it work correctly?

Comment: You're using `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` as well to resolve the locale from the `Accept` header. It will not allow you to change the locale through request parameters.

Comment: The bean id is wrong, it should be 'localeResolver', hence Spring is registering the default AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.

Comment: pluralsight xD, it did not work for me for that I am here

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change the bean id from "localResolver" to "localeResolver"

Comment: Yes, thanks, this solution works and it was mentioned in comment under my question.

Comment: Old post. still relevant. Wast breaking my head where did I do wrong. Saved my day. Thanks

Comment: I literally spent half of the day one this until I decided to re-read this comment. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this issue by naming the method as localeResolver using the solution provided here [Spring 4 i18n & l10n (Cannot change HTTP accept header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428249/spring-4-i18n-l10n-cannot-change-http-accept-header/45309703)

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
{
    final SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
    return localeResolver;
}
```

Comment: I spent 1 hour on this, just to discover that was the issue. Spring is so annoying sometimes <.<

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the basename.

I have two message files: messages_en_US.properties, messages_zh_CN.properties.

the basename should be "messages".

So that spring can detect if a parameter is en_US or zh_CN.