# Spring 4 i18n & l10n (Cannot change HTTP accept header)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization

I need help to solve this error message. Im working with spring 4 and I want to implement i18n & l10n on my project.
When I try to change language this message appears.
Below follows my code.
Please, anyone could help me with this issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKJp7.jpg

#### Output:

```
ago 21, 2014 10:29:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/webapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy] with root cause
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setLocale(AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle(LocaleChangeInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

### Config:

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/resources/locale/locale");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
```

### JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ page language="java" session="true" %>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>${title}</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1><spring:message code="label.title" /></h1>
    <h3>${pageContext.response.locale}</h3>
    <h4>Language : </h4><a href="?lang=en">English</a> | 
    <a href="?lang=pt">Portuguese Brazillian</a>    

    <!-- Logout form -->
    <h1>This is secured!</h1>
    <p>Hello <b><c:out value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}" /></b></p>
    <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout" />
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

### Files:

```
locale.properties:
label.title = Hello World

locale_pt.properties:
label.title = Ola Mundo
```

Comment: Rename your `sessionLocaleResolver` to `localeResolver`. That specific bean is looked up by name not by type. Spring expects a bean with the name `localeResolver`.

Comment: unbelievable :|. Thank you. This solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem lies in your configuration

```
@Bean
public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
    return localeResolver;
}
```

This constructs a bean with the name `sessionLocaleResolver` however the [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html)  looks for a bean with the name `localeResolver`. If this isn't detected it will use the default, which is a [`AcceptHeaderLocaleResovler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.html).

The solution is quite simple rename your method to `localeResolver` or include a `name` attribute in the `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() { ... }
```

or

```
@Bean(name="localeResolver")
```

Comment: Even the name of the method ("localeResolver()") must be the same!

Comment: No it doesn't, adding a `name` attribute to the `@Bean` annotation also works, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Bravo! It is real answer and solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

From this [blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/cannot-change-http-accept-header-use-a-different-locale-resolution-strategy/) which helped solve my issue for the same,

> In Spring MVC application, if you do not configure the Spring’s
>   LocaleResolver, it will use the default AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver,
>   which does not allow to change the locale. To solve it, try declare a
>   SessionLocaleResolver bean in the Spring bean configuration file, it
>   should be suits in most cases.

The solution was to declare this bean,

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by naming the method as localeResolver using the solution provided above by M.Deinum.

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
{
    final SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
    return localeResolver;
}
```